# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class example.webApp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I created simple servlet and deployed it to tomcat server but I got the following error: `HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class example.webApp`
Screenshot :

[image]

webApp.java:

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class webApp extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("Testing tomcat") ;
    }
}
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>example.webApp</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I  write `localhost:8080/test/test` to the Eclipse Browser I get upper above. If I enter `localhost:8080/test/test` again, I get this error:http://i.hizliresim.com/YBYE4z.png

I am confused. Can you help me? What is wrong?
Sorry to give picture links because I couldn't update directly to this website.

The first picture's text is :

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class example.webApp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class example.webApp
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.webApp
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the `Apache Tomcat/8.0.24` logs.

Comment: The first error is an InternalServerError, the second is a PageNotFound... So the first error lets your server crash... So that the second time the server is down... Probably your error is in `resp.getWriter().println("Testing tomcat") ;`... If you remove that... Then you'd get (well nothing) but each time... Please provide the StackTrace from the first error (500)... Here it says problem instantiating... Need to see where

Comment: It appears you're new to reading exceptions. The most important information of the exception is missing: the root cause.

Comment: I edited my question to provide Stack Trace.

Comment: Well, there is the answer. The specified class could not be found in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when creating servlet the class file may not be generated in build folder. We should clean the project then build. It worked for me. 
http://i.hizliresim.com/OqYz0n.png

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and run.
If you are using eclipse **Project -> Clean**

for NetBeans try Run -> Clean and Build Project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ya i was not able to add comment..and i tried the above code, it gave the same error later i cleaned and ran the project, it worked so gave the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write in your web.xml 
`<servlet-class>example.webApp.Test</servlet-class>` instead of `<servlet-class>example.webApp</servlet-class>`